# A group is abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite  group. For any two elements $a,b \neq e\in G$ there exits an automorphism $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(a)=b$. Prove that $G$ is abelian.

Only thing that I could conclude about the problem is that all elements have the same order.

Comment: Choose $a = e$ to conclude that $G$ is trivial. Or say $a,b \in G\setminus \{e\}$.

Comment: Is the statement still true if one detrivializes it by having the requirement only be for nontrivial $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @RghtHndSd It is. Think about what the order of the elements can be.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Certainly the order must be prime, but I don't see how this is sufficient.

Comment: Oops, I see it.

Comment: @RghtHndSd Oops, I don't know if it's true for infinite groups, only thought about finite. It's true for finite groups, regardless of what the prime is.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Both the order of an element and abelian are local properties, so the proof for finite groups carries over to the case where the group is locally finite (i.e. in this case where a single nontrivial element has finite order). A free group clearly doesn't satisfy the hypothesis.

Comment: Wait, is a finitely generated group where every element is of order $p$ necessarily finite? If not, my "proof" falls apart.

Comment: The answer to my previous question is [no](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_problem#Bounded_Burnside_problem).

Comment: The hypothesis that $G$ is finite is missing, otherwise this is false (when written with $a,b\neq e$). There are infinite (countable) groups with 2 conjugacy classes, it's not hard to construct using iterated HNN-extensions.

Comment: I cant understand why order of each element should be prime.Can you please explain this step@Daniel